# How to access events created by user in Facebook API by using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-events, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

I know very basic of javascript and this is my second call to Facebook API and I am having a problem. I need to read the list of user's events. Here is my code inside a function:

```
FB.api('/me/events', function(response) {
        console.log("event id: " + response.data[0].id);  
    });
```

Output is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

I tried to outout this:

```
FB.api('/me/events', function(response) {
        console.log("event id: " + response.data[0]);  
    });

event id: undefined
```

I have already created couple of events and join couple of events. And also I used this:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {

      var str="<b>Name</b> : "+response.name+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Link: </b>"+response.link+"<br>";
```

And it works fine. So there shouldn't be a problem with user login. I appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: What's in the `response` object?

Comment: Did you ask the user for the permission necessary to access their events?

Comment: @Tobi I got this piece of code from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/         and I need to access these but I dont have event id:     https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/event

Comment: @Bernard That doesn't answer my question. Do a `console.log(response);`

Comment: @CBroe Thanks mate I didn't give permission. If you can write your answer I accept for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask the user for `user_events` permission, before you can access their events.